# Update query run without error but do not update database ios sqlite objective C

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I am running SQLite query on my database. The select query is working fine, but when I am running SQLite query no error is generated, but it is still not updating my database values.
The function is as follows :

```
@try {
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bikeapp.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
    }

    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE bikes SET to_show = 0 where id = %ld",(long)bikeId];
    //const char *sql = "UPDATE bikes SET to_show = 0 where id = 3";
    const char *sql = [query UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement");
    }
    if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement))
    {

        return YES;
    }else
        return NO;


    //

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"An exception occured: %@", [exception reason]);
}
```

The code runs through without any error or exception but it is not updating the values inside the database. The query when run directly on database shows the changes being done. If anybody can help me out here I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: There are so many issues with your code. But your immediate issue is that the app's bundle is read-only.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply sorry i started back in ios after 6 years gap so still getting the knack of things.. can you help me out where can i make the changes to make it work.. from read only to writable.. thank you